# Does RAM increase also need BIOS upgrade in Gigabyte H110M-S2PH-CF motherboard?

Tags: memory, upgrade

Greetings from India.This is my first question in this forum.

My motherboard is Gigabyte H110M-S2PH-CF and processor is i5 7400 @3Hz 4core, 4 threads with 8GB DDR4 RAM. I want to upgrade it to 32 GB RAM. A local vendor has suggested me to upgrade my BIOS too. In order to increase RAM, is it necessary upgrade my BIOS too?

Thanks and Best regards.

Sukumar

Comment: The specifications do not say anything about the relation between RAM and the Bios version. Why wouldn't you want the BIOS upgraded?

Comment: I am not a Hardware expert, so it may sound stupid. But I heard that any mistake in BIOS upgrade may render my PC useless. Further, I don't have Windows installed in my machine, as I work exclusively on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 to be precise, in this PC). The BIOS update available in Gigabyte site is an exe file. I am not sure if it can be used  through wine and upgrade can be done. Any advice on this matter will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the usual case, there is no relation between RAM upgrade and BIOS version.

However, in some instances of hardware updates, newer BIOS updates enable
the motherboard to correctly identify new hardware such as processors, RAM,
and so on. If you upgraded your processor or RAM and the BIOS doesn’t recognize it,
a BIOS flash might be the answer.

The last
[BIOS update for the GA-H110M-S2PH](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H110M-S2PH-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios)
dates from 2‎018/04/16 and is described very shortly as "Update CPU microcode",
which doesn't help much.

The usual reason to avoid BIOS update is the fear of making a mistake and
bricking the computer. But in your case the update is offered by the vendor,
which is supposedly entirely capable of avoiding mistakes or of correcting
them if made.

So go ahead and accept the BIOS update. Even though it's not a new version,
your current version must be older than that.

Comment: Dear harrymc, Thanks a lot. Regards